Configuring ExpressJS CORS for use with EventSource/SSE
I am having an issue interacting with my ExpressJS notification (/client_notifications) endpoint using fetchEventSource in React. On my initial preflight request it seems to work:

However when I continue to attempt to poll that endpoint with a GET request I get the CORS error:
Access to fetch at 'https://api.healthinbound.com/client_notifications' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
So it seems like the preflight request works but the following requests do not. I have tried setting the appropriate headers but to no avail. Keep in my my other routes, that do not use SSE work fine.
Here is my app.js (note the commented out code that are other attempts):
const clientNotificationEventsHandler =
  require("./notificationsEventHandlers/clientNoti").notificationEventsHandler;

const app = express();

app.use(cors({withCredentials: true, origin: true}));

// app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS");

  
// if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
//   console.log("OPTIONS FOUND")
//   return res.status(200).end();
// }
//   next();
// });


app.get("/client_notifications", clientNotificationEventsHandler)

Here is the backend server code for the client_notifications endpoint/clientNotificationEventsHandler:
async function notificationEventsHandler(req, res) {
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS"
    //   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS");
  };
  // console.log("REQUEST", req)

  const clientEmail = req.headers.clientemail;

  const data = await ApptNotificationData.findAll({
    where: {
      patientEmail: clientEmail,
      accepted: "1",
    },
  });


  res.writeHead(200, headers); // THOUGHT THIS WOULD DO THE TRICK
  await res.write(`data:${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);  

  const newClientStream = {
    clientEmail: clientEmail,
    res,
  };

  clientStreams.push(newClientStream);

  req.on("close", () => {
    console.log(`${clientEmail} Connection closed`);
    clientStreams = clientStreams.filter(
      (client) => client.clientEmail !== client.clientEmail
    );
  });

  return res;
}

edit:
nginx.conf
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name api.***.com;

        location /client_notifications {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name api.***.com www.api.***.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/final.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.key;


    location /client_notifications {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }


    #root var/www/html;
    index index.php  index.html index.htm;
}

I thought it would be as easy as writing the proper headers to the response object in my handler function but clearly that is not the case, any help here?
Thank you in advance

You should get rid of all those extra Access-Control-Allow-* headers in your notificationEventsHandler(). The cors() middleware already takes care of that and does it properly

Judging by the https:// and redacted URL, this appears to have been deployed somewhere. How are requests routed through from the front proxy / load balancer to your Express app? Also, what do you see if you try and directly open the URL in your browser?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

cors({withCredentials: true, origin: true}) is insecure. Avoid such CORS configuration at all costs.

@Phil My apologies for the late reply, I had an extremely busy weekend. When I remove the headers you suggested I receive the same error. Are you asking to see my nginx config? I updated the question to include it, I didnt even consider that may be the issue

@Phil if I try to visit the URL directly I get a 502 Gateway not found error

Well there's your problem, the request isn't even reaching your Express server. A 502 means that nginx could not proxy the request because your service isn't reachable. Are you sure http://nodejs:3000 is correct?

@Phil Yes it is correct as all the other endpoints work without issue.  It looks like the 502 error was happening because my app was still opening causing my backend to crash. I suspect though if I just add the correct headers to my proxy config it should be fine? If you want to submit an answer I'd gladly accept. Thank you for your help

Might be something specific to handling EventSource requests. See if any of the answers in this post help - EventSource / Server-Sent Events through Nginx. Also check the nginx logs if possible

This post on ServerFault too - For Server-Sent Events (SSE) what Nginx proxy configuration is appropriate?. The proxy_set_header Connection ""; seems important
